# Java framework for ATOM pub server

Tags: spring-boot, java-7, atom-feed, atompub

What Java framework/libs should I use in 2017 for implementing ATOM pub server.

Our technology stack on existing apps are Spring Framework (Spring Boot) and Java 7, so I preferr an framework that works nicely with Spring.

I have looked at `ATOM Hopper` and `Rome`, but both frameworks have not been actively mainteined since 2015.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more detailed into `Atom Hopper` and `Rome Tools` because:

1. It has received several commits in 2017 so it seems that it is more maintained then `Atom Hopper`
2. `Spring Framework` is providing abstraction over `Rome Tools`. Although we are not going to use `AbstractAtomFeedView`, this indicate that `Spring Framework` considers this library stable and production ready
3. `Rome Tools` has only two 3rd party dependencies
4. `Rome Tools` can expose records as Atom or RSS feeds